# Ruby style relational tables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ruby, database, relational-database

I know ruby (on rails) uses lots of "magic", but I use PHP, is there not a way of implementing the rails-like:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cards
end
```

in PHP it would make so many peoples lives so much easier. Are there perhaps frameworks/ORM's that provide similar functionality etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is an "Object Relational Mapper" (ORM). The one you cite is a component of the Rails framework, called ActiveRecord.

[PHP ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) is one project that attempts to provide this, though the last release was in July 2010. I haven't actually used it; I just switched to Rails. :)

Comment: I tell you, I'm becoming very tempted to do the same.

Comment: @Christopher - yeah. I don't like to bash PHP because I know some very smart developers working in it. But there is so much more energy and best practices and sharing going on in the Ruby community, so good things tend to happen there first and (maybe) filter back to PHP. At least, that's my impression, and part of why I switched (besides the fact that Ruby itself is so interesting). Eventually something else will be the New Hotness.

Comment: Indeed, PHP hasn't been the Great New Thing for a long time now. I do remember when it was, and I was thinking the same about it that you now do about Ruby, but that's a looong time ago.

Answer (score 2):

in CakePHP [there are relationships](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together) such as hasMany, belongsTo, hasOne, and hasAndBelongsToMany

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't have a ORM by itself, but there are several fairly usable ORM projects for it; I'm acquainted with [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/), and it's rather good (used e.g. in the Symfony framework, which resembles Ruby somewhat).